# What is the workflow of Continuous Integration using git

Tags: git, continuous-integration

I'm learning Continuous Integration. This is what I understand about CI now.

There's a `master` branch. If I start working on a new feature I create a new branch, let's call it `feature_branch`. I switch to this `feature_branch` and then I begin writing the code (for the feature). At the end of the day I need to merge. And this is where I have the first question. What exactly should I merge with what?

I suppose that I need to get all the new code (if there's any) from the `master` branch into my `feature_branch` - after that my `feature_branch` contains all the code from the `master` branch. Then I commit my new code (for the feature) into my `feature_branch`. And the second question arises - upon commiting the new code into `feature_branch` the automatic test should run **on this `feature_branch`**, right?

The last question - how do automatic tests run on a branch when I commit, is there any kind of special git-hook for this?

Comment: With respect to your first question, when you create a `feature_branch`, it's created for the purpose of adding some new functionality/feature. Once it's completed, you should take a pull of the master branch using `git pull` into your feature_branch so that the feature_branch is updated with the code in the master else you will receive `merge conflicts` which won't let you to commit the code. Once your `feature_branch` code is up-to-date, you can raise a `pull request` for your code so that it can be peer reviewed and it is your *`feature_branch` that will get merged into the master branch*.

Comment: @nrai Thank you, but implementation of a new feature may take days or even weeks. Continuous Integration says you should merge at least daily (not just once it's completed).

Comment: You should keep committing your code daily into your `feature_branch`, have automatic builds in place that will keep building your `feature_branch` from time to time and point out errors early. CI tools like Jenkins will keep monitoring your branch and run the unit and integration tests of your feature_branch to make sure they're not failing. You'll merge your `feature_branch` into `master` only when your functionality is complete and when your `feature_branch` build is successful. That way you'll be sure that `master` branch will not fail when `feature_branch` gets merged into it

Comment: I suppose that your workflow misses the CONTINUOUS part of CI - by the time the functionality is complete the feature_branch may diverge from the master significantly and this will require you to spend a lot of time on resolving merge conflicts - the thing that CI is supposed to prevent. This is my understanding of CI...